# How to Solve Error:Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm following an Tutorial from youtube and now I ran into an problem. When I sync the build File. Build Completes without any Error but when I run app connecting my Device it give me error of

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

But when I remove the line

```
 implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
```

It works Fine, but I need this library. So How can I resolve it.

My app build.gradle file is

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nepalpolice.cdp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and inside my lib folder , I have volley jar file.

I tried below solution but it didn't work for me.

One

android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}

and also using

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and also I deleted .gradle file and clean and rebuild project but didn't help either.
How can I solve this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happened to me and the solution was about the release of the image cropper library.

In my case and as well yours, the SDK is 26 so you need to compile 2.5.1 version, not 2.6.0:

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
```

[Android Image Cropper releases](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/releases)

Comment: Thanks Jagar , it solved my problem..I was literally searching for solution for 3 hours.